# Firefox developer tools: restrict messages to current site

Tags: firefox, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

Is there any way of filtering out non-website warnings and errors?

I’m trying to use the console to troubleshot my JavaScript code, but the console is cluttered with messages from other sources such as Firefox addons. I some cases I can’t find my own `console.log` messages because of these messages.

Is there some sort of flag or setting to limit messages to the current site?

Answer (score 0):

Only the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (available e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or Firefox Menu > *More Tools* > *Browser Console*) shows messages coming from all different sources including add-ons.

The normal [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) within the Firefox DevTools (available e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> > *Console*) only contains messages from the current website.

So, you should ensure you're looking at the right console. If you're sure you are using the right console, then it's a bug and you should [report it to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=DevTools).